# ¿Es correcto decir “largoplacista”?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

¿Es largoplacista la forma correcta del antónimo de [cortoplacista](https://dle.rae.es/cortoplacista)? y ¿Cómo se escribiría largoplacista como compuesto o largo placista?

Comment: _a largo plaza_  seria posible

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/largoplacista

Comment: @mdewey Se podría decir "a largo plazo" (masculino).

Comment: Se que se puede cambiar por "a largo plazo"  pero la pregunta viene dada porque la RAE sí indica que existe cortoplacista (adj) y sin embargo el antónimo de la misma no :)

Comment: @Gustavson mi dispraxia de teclado otra vez.

Comment: @Alex, el hecho de que la palabra no esté todavía incorporada en el diccionario no significa que no exista o no se use. De hecho, si googleas encontrarás muchos buenos ejemplos de "largoplacista" y "largoplacismo". Yo no dudaría en usarla.

Comment: Por lo general, se usa a largo/corto plazo. Pero, bueno, tambien se puede largo/cortoplacista. Por ejemplo: Una política del gobierno a largo plazo, o largoplacista. Sí las dos no se encuentran en la RAE, nada impide utilizarlos en la medida que siguen la lógica del idioma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some time since this was asked the DLE has acknowledged the existence of [largoplacista](https://dle.rae.es/largoplacista).

La palabra [largoplacista](https://dle.rae.es/largoplacista) ahora existe in el DLE

> 1. adj. Que persigue resultados o efectos a largo plazo. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.